# Adding to while executing a list of commands

Tags: shell-script, gnu-parallel

I'm compiling a huge list of commands (all doing the same thing) I want executed, but as it takes a long time to compile that list, I would like execution to begin before I'm done (execution of each command typically takes longer than creating another, so there's no real risk of the list running dry).

The normal way to execute a list of commands, is to write a shell script listing the commands, but when I start execution of a script I can't add to it anymore.

The way I've found so far is to put the commands in `command.list` and having `parallel --jobs 1 --line-buffer :::: command.list`, but as it involves using `parallel` (I'm using GNU parallel, I don't know if it will work with the program in more-utils) for non-parallel execution of things, I think it's a bit of an abuse of `parallel`.

Is there a simpler way of doing it? Something that tracks which commands have been executed in case I screw up something and the list does run out, would be nice.

Comment: Can't you just do `sh ./command.list` or `sh <(tail -n+1 -f command.list)`

Comment: `sh ./command.list` does not discover new commands added to the list. The solution with `tail` seems to do what I want, but unlike the solution with `parallel` it doesn't exit when the list is empty (I don't really know which I prefer).

Comment: `sh ./command.list` should discover new commands added to the list as long as they are added to the list before `sh` has reached the end of it. You could also just do `sh <(command-that-generates-that-list)` or just `command-that-generates-that-list | sh` if the commands do not read their stdin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#example-gnu-parallel-as-queue-system-batch-manager

```
true >jobqueue; tail -n+0 -f jobqueue | parallel --joblog my.log &
echo my_command my_arg >> jobqueue
my_job_generator >> jobqueue
```

This will give you a record (my.log) of which jobs have completed.

GNU Parallel version 20220222 will only output job *n* (and add it to `my.log`) when job *n+1* has been added. If that is unacceptable, just add another dummy-job:

```
echo true dummy >> jobqueue
```

The behaviour is slightly different in older versions.

Comment: `--joblog` seems like a very valuable thing (why didn't I check the documentation to see if such a feature was implemented, `parallel` has so many features), and getting an answer from the author of the software makes it feel less like an abuse of the software.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity GNU Parallel has become better by being abused: Several bugs have been uncovered by users using it in ways it was never designed to support - and fixing the bugs have improved reliability. So abuse away. :)

Comment: @OleTange it seems that using `-u` will make the job output available as soon as it  finishes, but joblog will still be updated only after another job has started. Is there a way to make `--joblog` follow the same behavior?

Comment: @LucasMenicucci `-u` prints the output without buffering. It does not wait until the job is done. `--joblog` is only updated after the job is done.

Comment: Got it, thanks!